# Xamarin.forms / Android Facebook get Friends

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hi everyone I'm using Xamarin.Forms to create an application. I've been able to create a facebook login and retrieve user ID. I'm now trying to get the friendlist of the user. I understood that only user who have accepted the app can be shown, however I cant see the one who identified in my app ( I have a friend as test user) Here's my code:

```
    private void getFriends() {
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient (App.Token);

        fb.GetTaskAsync ("me/friends").ContinueWith (t => {
            try {
                var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)t.Result;
                var data = (IList<object>)result ["data"];

                foreach (IDictionary<string, object> friend in data) {
                    App.addFriendToList ((string)friend ["name"], (string)friend["id"]);
                }
            } catch {
                App.addFriendToList ("No Friends Using imin", "0000");
            }
        });
    }
```

The code is for android. The code is inspired (not to say copy pasted) from the Xamarin Facebook SDK. So it should work. It is working however the list supposed to display friend remain empty ( note that i do not catch any errors).

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: is the problem that you're getting the data, but the UI is not displaying it?  Or that you're not getting the data in the first place?  Those are two different issues, and you need to figure out which one you need to solve.

Comment: I've been digging and maybe my UI doesn't update, i will try phillipe answer just below.

Answer (score 0):

The callback in `ContinueWith` actually runs on a different synchronization context. The UI probably doesn't get updated. Try doing this:

```
private void getFriends() {
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient (App.Token);

    // There call for "Result" here will wait for the task to complete before returning.
    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.GetTaskAsync ("me/friends").Result;
    var data = (IList<object>)result ["data"];

    foreach (IDictionary<string, object> friend in data) {
        App.addFriendToList ((string)friend ["name"], (string)friend["id"]);
    }
}
```

Please not that this WILL block the UI thread and the application will remain unresponsive during the Get call. Something like this would be preferable:

```
private async Task getFriends() {
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient (App.Token);

    //Here the call to ConfigureAsync(true) will force the synchronization context back to the one before the call (the UI thread in this case)
    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)(await fb.GetTaskAsync ("me/friends").ConfigureAsync(true));
    var data = (IList<object>)result ["data"];

    foreach (IDictionary<string, object> friend in data) {
        App.addFriendToList ((string)friend ["name"], (string)friend["id"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think effectively that my UI is not updating: I use a Listview to display a list of object friend built with name and id. Does the listview display the whole content of the list from which it is sourced at anytime, or do you need to update and redo (ListView.ItemsSource = yourlist ) for it to update the display ? If so I'll have to find a workaround

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Android UI, but I don't see why you'd have to reassign the source if the reference doesn't change... There's probably a way to force the redraw or something like that!

Comment: Well if it is from a List<> no, you can't modify the source it throw an exception, I had to use a ObservableCollections<> to be able to modify the source.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i just made a silly mistake, did not init the List I used to store the friends, should have checked twice. My initial code is working fine with that.